# How can I use the 3G feature on my Acer TravelMate 8572?

Tags: laptop, 3g, acer-travelmate

I've just been given a TravelMate 8572 to work on at a client. A highlight was seeing that this machine apparently has built in 3G, but nowhere in any of the three manuals I've downloaded does it even mention 3G.

Can anyone suggest how I can use this 3G feature, and how to place my SIM card in the 3G module?

**EDIT:**  I found where to put the SIM card, in the battery bay, and this changed the info displayed in the 3G Connection Manager. However, my status tells me to turn the radio on using the switch on the notebook, but I only find one 'radio' switch, and toggling it turns the WLAN off. The Connection Manager help says to use it's Settings tab to switch radio on, but the settings tab is disabled, and on that tab it says that radio is on, so I don't know where I stand.

Comment: Could it be that only the Acer Travelmate 8572 **G** has the built in 3G?

Comment: No @soandos, it's there but not working. Please see my edit.

Comment: How are you sure its there? Does it show up in device manager?

Comment: I can't check the device manager now, but as I said in my edit, **the Connection Manager shows that a SIM has been inserted.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, as it seems to me, that the radio device in the TravelMate 8572 can be cycled between 3G, Bluetooth, and Wifi, and after pressing the Radio button a few times I happened onto the correct setting and everything now works nicely.